# What is the benchmark for mongodb search for typical foursquare like application?

Tags: mongodb

How much is fast for a query? .1 second? Or what?

My databases have 1.6 million businesses and user search based on location. What would be a good target to aim for speed?

How fast is reasonable?

Comment: You should ask your users what their requirements are.

Comment: This question has no serious answer, 100ms could be fast if that's what your looking for. We have no idea what you really want from a system

Comment: updated the question. What I am my own user, I mean the end user is people looking for restaurants.

Comment: I would say that a typical fs type app would never have a query response time longer than say 10ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with MongoDB's [own profiling level guideline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) which considers operations slower than 100ms to be slow:

> **By default slow operations are those slower than 100 milliseconds.**

With less than 100 ms read queries, users will typically not notice a delay on a web application where all non-db operations are performing optimally.